# Spring Data JPA how to avoid loading a column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Location {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "location_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID locationId;

    @NonNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ms")
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @NonNull
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UUID userId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "latitude", nullable = false)
    private Double latitude;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "longitude", nullable = false)
    private Double longitude;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @NonNull
    @Id
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UUID userId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "email", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "second_name", nullable = false)
    private String secondName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<Location> locations;
}
```

and then i have

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    User save(User user);
}
```

userRepository.save(user) - this method return User with all locations which referenced to this user.

I want to avoid this join query in sql since there could be a lot of referenced locations to the user. This could be cause of OutOfMemory etc. So, i want to get only User without List locations after
`userRepository.save(user)`

I tried to write query this way:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "update users " +
                "set email = :email, first_name = :firstName, second_name = :secondName " +
                "where user_id = :userId " +
                "returning user_id, email, first_name, second_name;")
    User update(
        @Param("userId") @NonNull String userId,
        @Param("firstName") @NonNull String firstName,
        @Param("secondName") @NonNull String secondName,
        @Param("email") @NonNull String email
    );
```

but got the same result with locations in response from DB

This is a hibernate log:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* dynamic native SQL query */ update
        users 
    set
        email = ?,
        first_name = ?,
        second_name = ? 
    where
        user_id = ? returning user_id, email, first_name, second_name;
Hibernate: 
    select
        locations0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_,
        locations0_.location_id as location1_0_0_,
        locations0_.location_id as location1_0_1_,
        locations0_.created_at as created_2_0_1_,
        locations0_.latitude as latitude3_0_1_,
        locations0_.longitude as longitud4_0_1_,
        locations0_.user_id as user_id5_0_1_ 
    from
        locations locations0_ 
    where
        locations0_.user_id=?
```

Comment: The list is lazy so it won't be loaded. Also why add the `save` method as that is already part of the default `CrudRepository`. If it is there it is probably because you are showing the full user in the front end (leading to the location to be loaded). Additionally the `@Repository` doesn't do anything on your interface remove it so you don't have that additional clutter.

Comment: Also, always include the full stacktrace. You are telling is there is an error in your code, but you leave out the part where the stacktrace even tells you exactly what the error is

Comment: The list is lazy but it is loaded in current implementation. I use debug to check whether if base `save` method return `user` with all locations. So it doesn't depends on frontend anyway.

Comment: @skubev your expectations are initially wrong: in `JPA` annotation `@OneToMany` is misspelled, the correct spelling is `@OneToFew`, just keep it in mind.

Comment: Debugging and inspecting the list will also load the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you get the locations field loaded due to debugging. Debugging triggers get method and it makes hibernate to load all locations.

Comment: It seems you're right. it helped me. Thanks a lot!